# NOT close telnet when supplying username and password using echo

Tags: login, echo, telnet, autologin

When I'm supplying username and password to telnet to login, it is automatically closed after the following command:

```
echo password | telnet mymachine -l mysuername
```

The console outputs:

```
Connected to mymachine.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Then the connection is closed. Is there a way to maintain the connection while still supplying username and password to the login at one time?

**Update:
I wrote an alias according to the accepted answer that does the login without typing username and password everytime:**

```
alias logon='rm loginscript; echo \#\!\/usr\/bin\/expect >> loginscript ; echo spawn telnet remotemachine -l username >> loginscript ; echo expect Password: >> loginscript ; echo send password"\\r" >> loginscript ; echo expect -- \{\$ \} >> loginscript ; echo interact >> loginscript; chmod 777 loginscript; ./loginscript'
```

Comment: You cannot do that, Have a look at `expect`

Comment: `expect` is best approach, as suggested.  A hack using `( sleep 1 ; echo username ; sleep 2 ; echo password ; sleep 2 ; echo ls ) | telnet mymachine` is possible but ugly/unreliable.

Comment: Have a look at sshpass.

Comment: The `login` command, which is responsible for querying your password, explicitly clears all input characters before prompting for the password, to avoid attacks through the console's clipboard buffer or the xterm window title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to continue with an interactive session, the usual way is to use `expect` to do the login:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet mymachine -l myusername
expect Password:
send password\r
expect -- {$ }
interact
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you still want to interact with that `telnet` session after sending the password, you'd need to feed it input from your local terminal:

```
(echo password; cat) | telnet -l user host
```

Depending on how your `telnet` implementation tries to interact with the local terminal, you may find that you need to do:

```
saved=$(stty -g); stty raw -echo
(echo password; cat) | telnet -l user host
stty "$saved"
```

Or even:

```
saved=$(stty -g); stty raw -echo
(echo password; cat) | telnet -l user host 2>&1 | cat
stty "$saved"
```

(on some systems, you may need `cat -u` in place of `cat`)

Another option is to [use `expect`](/a/315105) which uses a pseudo-terminal instead of pipes to interact with the application (note that `telnetd` also spawns a pty at the other end, so an extra one is not strictly necessary in this case).